# login error when I get to "wp-admin"

Tags: wordpress

1. I registered my new domain *"aaa.com"*
2. I made a subfolder *"bbb"* , installed wordpress in there.
3. I installed few plugins on *"aaa.com/bbb"*

   - Advanced custom fields
   - statcounter plugin
   - WP custom widget area
   - wp cerber
   - custom sidebars
4. I set up subdomain as *"bbb"*
5. I set *wp-home* url and *wp-site* url by *"bbb.aaa.com"* in options page.
6. subdomain seemed to work well.

   - when I go *"aaa.com/bbb"*, wp shows 404 page
   - url *"bbb.aaa.com"* works fine. when I clicks some permalink or page link, the urls look like *"bbb.aaa.com/postOrPageUrls"*
7. HOWEVER, there was a problem when I typed bbb.aaa.com/wp-admin

   1. WP redirected me to the login page - it was what I expected
   2. But, I couldn't entered admin page even though I typed ID,passwords.
   3. wp doesn't showed login errer message, It just refreshed everytime I press submit button.
   4. I typed url as *"aaa.com/bbb/wp-admin/"* and I could enter the admin page with that url.
8. I figured out that thre's difference between two login pages.

   - *"bbb.aaa.com/wp-admin"* redirects to *"bbb.aaa.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=**http**%3A%2F%2F**bbb.aaa.com**%2F**bbb**%2F**wp-admin**%2F&reauth=1"*
   - **wait, *"bbb.aaa.com/bbb/wp-admin/"* ?**
   - *"aaa.com/bbb/wp-admin"* redirects to *"bbb.aaa.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=**http**%3A%2F%2F**aaa.com**%2F**bbb**%2F**wp-admin**%2F&reauth=1"*
9. so that mean, the login page redirected from *"bbb.aaa.com/wp-admin"* points wrong address: bbb.aaa.com already points the subfolder bbb, but that login page finds the subfolder bbb again.
10. It was long story. now I'm trying to fix the problem. **login page - redirected by wp-admin - redirecting to wrong url.** Can I get some hints?

Comment: MySQL DB > wp_options > Change siteurl and homeurl to bbb.aaa.com ( No `/` at the end )

Comment: I checked wp_options but it already seems ok...